# Find value of expression based on variable equality instead of assignment

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation, linear-algebra

I have certain relations or equalities which determine how different variables are related to each other. These relations are meant to be used to further calculate the value of some other expression.

How can I do that in Mathematica? Here is an example:

```
P/Q = M/N = A/B = 5;       ... (1)
```

Then I need to evaluate:

```
(2*P^2 + 8*M^2 + 10*A^2)/(2*Q^2 + 8*N^2 + 10*B^2)     ... (2)
```

I could rewrite the first set of equations as:

```
P = 5*Q, M = 5*N and A = 5*B    ... (3)
```

This would work in this particular case. However, sometimes, there are many variables and complex relationships involved. Calculating values of all variables manually to supply them to Mathematica will be tedious.

Is there any way to get Mathematica to evaluate `2` by only supplying `1` without re-writing it in form `3`?

Thanks.

Update: Another such example would be:

```
X^2 + Y^2 + 1/X^2 + 1/Y^2 == 4
```

Then calculate:

```
X^2 + Y^2
```

Comment: I would caution against using capital letters for variables as some of them are reserved by the system (like C, D, E, I, K, N, and O). Also, in your second example, are you hoping to evaluate x^2 + y^2 and have it return 4 - 1/x^2 - 1/y^2?

Comment: @MassDefect the value of `X^2 + Y^2` is actually 2. I was hoping to get that in the result. Both `x` and `y` are real :)

Comment: @MassDefect I try to use small letters most of the times but sometime I forget because of my old habits. :)